# Jmeter reading input parameters from dynamically appending file

Tags: jmeter

Please tell me, is it possible to read data into Jmeter from a dynamically changing file? I have a file with parameters, which will be appended during the test itself. Is it possible to somehow define a global counter that will allow each thread to read its own line every iteration? User Defined Variables are reset every iteration as i understood.
In theory, I can read a specific line using File.readLines().get(*counter*) in JSR223 Sampler but problem is how to define correctly this *counter*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) is what you're looking for. If you invoke it like `${__counter(FALSE,)}` it will return an incremented value each time it will be called.

Example usage:

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)